# Splash screen on Android using Phonegap + Eclipse

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

I'm coding an Android app through Phonegap and I'm at the point of installing the Splashscreen.

I managed to install a landscape splashscreen using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156841/phonegap-splash-screen-for-android-app), but as I expected it doesn't recognize it as a landscape or portrait splashscreen, so it just displays the image, no matter the orientation of the device. How do I tell it should show the wide image when the device is in landscape and the high image when the device is in portrait mode?

I'm using:
- Eclipse
- Phonegap 1.5.0

*Edit: Question updated! See text below.*
Thanks to ghostCoder I got one step closer, but it still doesn't work.

Do I have to add something to the following code to draw the portrait images? (it still displays the landscape, no matter the orientation of the device)

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

This is how my folders look now:
[image: folders in res folder]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

have the folder structure of the res folder like this. now u can have the splash screen of landscape in the 'land' folders and of the portrait mode in folders without land. hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had a few days off, but I'll check it out now. Will keep you posted and accept the answer if it works.

Comment: It doesn't work by just adding the folders. I'll update my question

Comment: do both landscape and potrait images have the same name?

Comment: Yes, they are all called splash.png

Comment: errr, pls check my folder names...  try adding the v9 too wherever its thr

Comment: sorry, what does thr mean? And why add v9?