# Mobile App Splash screen sizes for all platforms using PhoneGap

Tags: html, cordova, splash-screen

I am building an app for iPhone, android and Blackberry, and I have put a splash screen image on with a size of 640 x 960 px. This works ok on my Galaxy S3 - bit stretched still, but it seems to differ for each device.

I basically want to know what sizes to make these splash screens. I have seen a lot around rthe web giving different views, and different sizes for each screen. Has anyone got an idea about what sizes are for where? Do I even need to make a different size for each screen? They all have different aspect ratios etc...

EDIT

Also, I have seen somewhere that you need different directories for android - specifically "res/drawable-ldpi, res/drawable-mdpi, res/drawable-hdpi, res/drawable-xdpi." Where do i fiond this on the PhoneGap build? I cant gain access to that part of the file directory, only the images etc.. that I have uploaded. I am using Dreamweaver CS6 by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see my previous answer on splash screen sizes?

[phonegap - splash screen for Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156841/phonegap-splash-screen-for-android-app/8157103#8157103)

Regardless, on Android you will need to provide multiple splash screen sizes or provide a [9-patch image](https://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) that will stretch properly.

Comment: Yeah I saw a similar post to this. Problem is I cant seem to locate the res directory, or the www or assets directories either. I think im missing something really important here... but I havent needed to because I have been using PhoneGap build service with Dreamweaver CS6.

Comment: Oh my god how stupid of me, you just unzip it with WinRAR or something. ARGHHHHH!!! Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

if you are using phonegap build or cli make a folder res in root. add this to config file and place screens according

```
 <gap:splash src="splash.png" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />

    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"    gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"     gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
```