# Custom PhoneGap slash screen

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Is it possible to replace the splash screen for iOS and Android with a custom one?

As far as I know there are 2 splash screens in iOS PhoneGap:

- The "normal" iOS splash screen
- The PhoneGap splash screen (same image with a spinner)

Would it be possible to:

- replace the "normal" iOS splash on runtime as it is possible with normal xCode Projects
- replace the "spinner" splash screen (I couldn´t figure out if that´s the phonegap-plugins / iPhone / SplashScreen code or not)

It seems that the normal xCode ways of doing things get overwritten. I´m a bit confused by that as I´m new to PhoneGap.

Comment: Regarding PhoneGap Android splash screen read:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156841/phonegap-splash-screen-for-android-app/8157103#8157103

Answer (score 10, accepted):

yeah,you can do that.

1. make your custom  image in 640×960px(name:Default@2x~iphone.png) and  320×480px(name:Default~iphone.png)
2. go to[Name Your Project]/Resources/splash
3. replace them..

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if I can change the path to the image? For example to something like ../Documents/ that I can change at runtime?