# Phonegap 2.0 - on app launch a white screen flashes prior to my app loading

Tags: android, cordova

How do you get rid of the white screen flash on android/phonegap application launches?  It appears to be showing the activity_main.xml for a split second,  I have tried changing the background color to black to make it less noticeable.  I assume there is a way to hide that altogether?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the WebView needs to be instantiated first and it defaults to a blank white page and then loadUrl is called which loads your application code. One way to get around it is to show a splashscreen until your app is loaded in the background.

[phonegap - splash screen for Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156841/phonegap-splash-screen-for-android-app/8157103#8157103)

Comment: Perhaps I'm doing something wrong,  I previously ran across this post and attempted it,  it added a splash screen,  but I STILL get the behavior in my question.  Now its a flash of the activity_main with a white background, then a splash screen, then my app.   Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the theme of your app, you can change the color of this flash background, eg: Light or Dark. This will minimise the effect.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the same issue.  I get around this by setting the activity layout background between init and loadUrl.  That way, I got the entire process cover: before splash screen shown, splash screen shown, splash screen hide, and then hide my splash screen after device ready.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
super.init();

// set the layout background
root.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
root.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splash);
root.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"));

super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl(), 80000);
```

To reduce code, I set my splash screen in config.xml:

```
<preference name="backgroundColor" value="0xffffffff" />
<preference name="splashscreen" value="splash" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="false" />
```

This is based on Cordova 2.8+.  Splash screen on 2.7 is kinda wack.

In addition, if you experience issue with white screen on iOS.  See iOS quirk section at bottom here:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html#Splashscreen