# Phonegap 3 white flash after splash

Tags: ios, cordova

I know this has been asked (and answered) several times ([Phonegap showing white screen after the splash screen - IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990396/phonegap-showing-white-screen-after-the-splash-screen-ios), [Phonegap 2.0 - on app launch a white screen flashes prior to my app loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159501/phonegap-2-0-on-app-launch-a-white-screen-flashes-prior-to-my-app-loading/17278377#17278377), [how to to kill the white flickering splashscreen at the start of phonegap iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992939/how-to-to-kill-the-white-flickering-splashscreen-at-the-start-of-phonegap-ios-ap/7788187#7788187)) but none of these solutions seem to be working for me.  Maybe because I'm using Phonegap version 3?

I'm only loading Phonegap and jQuery 2.0.0 (other solutions deal with jQuery-mobile which I'm not using) and I'm only targeting iOS for deployment.  I've got a splash image loading, then the app displays a white screen (duration varies - I'm guessing it's loading up the app perhaps?) then my index.html loads up my first screen.  Here's my current head:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />

    <title>My App</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>      
</head>
```

I tried adding this to my config.xml (at the same folder level as index.html):

```
<preference name="backgroundColor" value="0x000000" />
```

but I still get the white screen flash.  I also tried manually hiding/showing the splash with:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.splashscreen.show();
}
```

but that didn't seem to have any effect at all.  Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: +1 I am having the same problem. Have you made any progress?

Comment: @FlyingLemon: I was able to resolve this through trial-and-error debugging.  My steps are listed below.

Answer (score 18):

I was finally able to eliminate the splash flash, but I had to use Cordova to do it.  Here are the steps I took:

In Terminal:

```
cordova create ~/path/to/project “com.appname.app” “appName”
cd ~/path/to/project
cordova platform add ios
cordova build
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git
cordova build
```

Use Finder to navigate to `~/path/to/project/platforms/ios/` and double-click `projectname.xcodeproj` to open the project in Xcode.

Next, I went in and edited the images.  You could do it any number of ways.  Here's what I did: In Xcode, navigate to `Resources/splash/`, right-click the image to change, select `Show in Finder` and use whatever tools you want to change the images.

Once finished, head back to Xcode and open the root-level `config.xml` (Still not sure why there are two `config.xml` files, but you want the one furthest out in the folder structure).  Update the `AutoHideSplashScreen` property to

`<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />`.

From the Xcode main menu, select `Product > Clean` and then `Product > Build`.

Worked for me repeatedly.  I was able to then use the `navigator.splashscreen.show()` and `navigator.splashscreen.hide()` methods from my app (which didn't seem to be responding without going through all these steps).

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 **That was it.** Every plugin has to be added manually to the project now, using CLI tool. PS: **It also works without splashscreen.hide/show event.**

Comment: I'm still a bit confused as to the syntax between Phonegap v Cordova projects, as the online docs reference a Cordova project. This ended up working for me:

`phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git`

Comment: In my case after installation I had to remove `<param name="onload" value="true" />` from SplashScreen `<feature>` node in config.xml file (I use Cordova 3.3.0)

Comment: @brian flanagan - regarding the "duplicate" config.xml files - I believe the inner one (inside the specific platform) is created automatically when you build (e.g.`cordova build ios`). Thus, any changes should be done to the outer config.xml as you written above...

Answer (score 4):

I have a problem with the plugins or some problem with phonegap so

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.splashscreen.show();
}
```

doesn't work for me.

I fixed it by setting the webview alpha to 0 until it's loaded:

3 steps:

1. in the file `"CDVViewController.m"` in method  "`-(void)createGapView`" I added:
   self.webView.alpha=0;
2. in the file `"MainViewController.m"` in method "`-(void)WebViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView"` I added:     `theVebView.alpha=1;`
3. in the file `"MainController.xib"` I changed the background to black (set it to any color you prefer).

Now instead of a white screen flash I have a black one until the content is fully loaded.
good enough for me. (although not perfect)

hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

try Add

`<param name="onload" value="true" />`  to your SplashScreen feature in config.xml.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using build.phonegap.com

Step 1: Added the Slashscreen plugin to your config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" version="0.2.7" />
```

Step 2: Update your config.xml with this preference.

```
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="false" />
```

Step 3: Added the plugin function call to your 'deviceready' event

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  function onDeviceReady() {
   navigator.splashscreen.hide()
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting mad with the splash plugin, I find out this solution:

1. in MainViewController.xib, add a UIImageView (imgView).
2. put your splash image in it, set scale to fill.
3. In MainViewController.m, override - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView
4. add these code after [super webViewDidFinishLoad:theWebView];

   [self.view sendSubviewToBack:imgView];

   imgView.hidden = YES;