# White flash and transition issue on Jquery Mobile & Phonegap 3

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-plugins, splash-screen

I hate to ask a question that has been asked before, but I am suffering from the white flash when transitioning from the splash screen to main page on IOS (no flashes at all on android), and I have tried all the other suggestions listed in other posts ([Phonegape 3 white flash after splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006762/phonegap-3-white-flash-after-splash) ), and none of them worked.

In fact, the suggestion of manually adding in the splash screen plugin and using the splashscreen.show / hide actually has made things worse, the white flash now stays present for 3-5 seconds before moving to the main page.

I've also noticed that my app seems to be ignoring the

`<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />`

command, as I have this set in the config.xml file, and the splashscreen shows when the app launches, stays up for a few seconds, and then moves on, when the expected behavior is that it would stay up indefinitely (until I tell it to go away via the splashscreen.hide() command).

Would anyone have any other suggestions for removing or drastically reducing the white flash after the splash screen?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried including the following config.xml values if they aren't already there?:

```
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true"/>
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="0.7"/>
<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
```

I had the same problem a few weeks ago and adding these fixed it for me.