# Cordova iOS Splash Screen

Tags: ios, cordova, splash-screen

I can't make the splash screen stay until the page is loaded.
I have read every entry in the first, second and third page of google search. I read all the questions posted here on stackoverflow including [A good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006762/phonegap-3-white-flash-after-splash) but none seem to work.

What's worse is that the behavior I'm seeing is all wrong. Following the instructions [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html#Splashscreen) I added alert at the *deviceready* event and I saw it happens after the white page is gone and my initial page is loaded.
I installed the plugin and included the following in the root level config.xml:

```
<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

I am still getting Splash->White screen->My initial page.
I am using Cordova 3.3.0 with ionicframework.
What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I think it might have something to do with this error message:

> The splashscreen image named Default-Portrait was not found

Comment: Please make sure you are using right names and size of splash screen. Default-Portrait~ipad.png -- 768 x 1004
Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png - 1536 x 2008
Default~iphone.png - 240x 320
Default@2x~iphone.png - 640x960
Default-568h@2x~iphone.png - 640x1136

Comment: Yes, that was it. The default name was wrong.

Comment: You might want to mark this answered if your problem is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gorpal said in a comment

> Please make sure you are using right names and size of splash screen. Default-Portrait~ipad.png -- 768 x 1004 Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png - 1536 x 2008 Default~iphone.png - 240x 320 Default@2x~iphone.png - 640x960 Default-568h@2x~iphone.png - 640x1136

which worked for me. It's all about the correct name.

Answer (score 5):

I have just had the same issue and found that Gopal's answer was not the solution (as I already had my files named and sized correctly).

Instead I found this answer to be correct: [Cordova 3.4 iOS white screen after splash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285888/cordova-3-4-ios-white-screen-after-splash/22354322#22354322)

**Alternate solution in brief:**
Duplicate your "Default@2x~iphone.png" and rename it to "Default-Portrait@2x~iphone.png". Then drag that file into your Project Files in XCode under "Resources/Splash" so that it is recognised when Xcode builds.

Comment: This worked for me to. Only renaming like Shy said didn´t.

Answer (score 3):

If cordova-plugin-splashscreen can not find images, you can specify UILaunchImageFile key in plist.

```
<key>UILaunchImageFile</key>
<string>LaunchImage</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I just added the key, `Launch Image` on the Info tab, similar to Nikita's answer:

[image]