# Cordova Platform iOS 4.0.1 White Screen

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova

I am using Cordova 6.0.0 and I upgrade to iOS platform 4.0.1

Whenever I try to run the ios app and according to the Xcode dev console it goes through all the stages of loading, then stops at 'Resetting plugins due to page load." The device it's just an unresponsive white screen. I've put in debug statements, and I know for a fact that deviceready is firing correctly.

Here is the log from Xcode 7.2

> 2016-03-04 12:49:19.499 MyApp[3858:1510716] Apache Cordova native
>   platform version 4.0.1 is starting.
>
> 2016-03-04 12:49:19.501 MyApp[3858:1510716] Multi-tasking -> Device:
>   YES, App: YES
>
> 2016-03-04 12:49:19.689 MyApp[3858:1510716] Using UIWebView
>
> 2016-03-04 12:49:19.692 MyApp[3858:1510716] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl]
>   0.120997ms
>
> 2016-03-04 12:49:19.698 MyApp[3858:1510716]
>   [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 4.896998ms
>
> 2016-03-04 12:49:19.698 MyApp[3858:1510716] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler]
>   0.104964ms
>
> 2016-03-04 12:49:19.723 MyApp[3858:1510716] [CDVTimer][localstorage]
>   25.017977ms
>
> 2016-03-04 12:49:19.723 MyApp[3858:1510716]
>   [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 30.952990ms
>
> 2016-03-04 12:49:20.235 MyApp[3858:1510716] Resetting plugins due to
>   page load.
>
> 2016-03-04 12:49:51.516 MyApp[3858:1510716] Received memory warning.

Any help please?

Comment: let see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285888/cordova-3-4-ios-white-screen-after-splash?rq=1

Comment: You should take a look into Web Inspector JavaScript console to see to further errors

Comment: Any update on this? I am seeing a similar behavior after upgrading an existing app to use Cordova 6 (using Ionic/Angular) where the thing loads but becomes unresponsive to touch

Comment: I make an update to Cordova 6.1.0 and the app is running without any problem now.

Answer (score 0):

Switch off the device and back on again. Then run via Xcode again, and see if the message is gone. If it's gone, then you or the Cordova libs probably locked up some memory.