# Cordova - iOS 10 - Splash Screen not working

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm using Cordova 6.5.0 with platform ios 4.3.1. I have installed the SplashScreen plugin and am using [Legacy Launch Images](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/#legacy-launch-images)

I have prepared splash screen images of the below sizes, added them in config.xml and placed them in project_folder/res/screen/ios

```
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>

<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
```

After building the app, I can see in Xcode that all the above images are reflected in the LaunchImage asset catalog under unassigned category.

When I run the app on iPhone 5 (iOS 10), I get a launch screen followed by a white screen (with loading indicator) for 1 second, followed by the app's main screen. Also in the Xcode console, I can see the below warning

```
WARNING: The splashscreen image named Default-568h was not found
```

Whereas I expect it to display the splash screen for 10 seconds (SplashScreenDelay)

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/22354322/3901620

Comment: @KKRocks: I've already tried this, but the behaviour is same.

Comment: You have two images for 640x1136. Check which one do you really have in res/screen/ios/ and only reference that in the config.xml. Also make sure that it really have that size.

Comment: @jcesarmobile: I removed the above configuration and rebuild the code, but the same issue

Comment: If you removed it, update your question with your current values

Answer (score -1):

Follow the syntax in  [Legacy Launch Image](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/#legacy-launch-images). There is no `<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-568h.png" width="640" height="1136"/>` in the config.xml

Comment: I removed the above configuration and rebuild the code, but the same issue

Comment: @Sahil Did you tried placing the above entry in config.xml and tried again? After removing the config, any error on console while loading splash screen?

Comment: @Gandhi: I get the same warning in console "WARNING: The splashscreen image named Default-568h was not found"

Comment: @sahil do you have that image placed in your project with that respective name?

Comment: @Gandhi: Where do you want the image to be available in the project? I have Default-568h.png in Images.xcassets