# How to fix while screen after splash screen in cordova ios?

Tags: javascript, cordova

While developing cordova app, I notice white screen after the splash screen and before html page.

Is there any solution to get rid off white screen?

I am facing this issue in iPhone app, I have used cordova helloWorld app so this issue is not related to plugins.

Cordova v7.0.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cordova 3.4 iOS white screen after splash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285888/cordova-3-4-ios-white-screen-after-splash)

Comment: @RamblinRose thanks, but that solution is outdated and it doesn't solve my problem with xcode 9 and iPhone x.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably facing the same issue I was facing a while ago. Start off by not auto hiding the splash screen. Instead hide it on "deviceready".

To stop autohiding splash screen add the following line to config.xml

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

To manually hide splash screen add the following inside the deviceready event in your entry point( probably index.html or the js file you are using in it for app namespace )

```
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
```

For more information, head to [cordova-plugin-splashscreen documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/).