# IOS splash screen is implemented and executed, a white screen appears. To display an image?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

Error: I created the required screens with the main storyboard, created and executed the splash page as a finishing step, and the splash page did not work properly.
When you insert the image into the splash page and run it, instead of the image appearing,
a white screen appears and then moves on to the main storyboard page.
so I've been looking for Googleing and Stackoverflow, but I can't find a solution

attempt: xcode > new file > Launch Screen(save name: LaunchScreen)
I set Launch screen file as LaunchScreen. Just in case, I made another project and tried the same way, but the splash screen went very well on that project. What is the problem?

Code: [AppDelegate.swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0NTo.png)

I found it while I was looking at the stackoverflow. Is it the same error?
[Cordova 3.4 iOS white screen after splash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285888/cordova-3-4-ios-white-screen-after-splash/22354322#22354322)
Please help me. I want to fix the error.

Answer (score 6):

The images used in `launch.storyboard` should not be put in `Assets.xcassets/xxx.imageset`,

The images in `launch.storyboard` should be put in the project directly, or a folder in the project.

- Then use the image as `xxx.png`, and the IOS splash screen is normal.
- On the other side, if the image is used as `xxx`, when put in `xxx.imageset` ,the IOS splash screen is white blank.

Comment: I tried a lot of solutions for a long time. But only this worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check Launch Images option. It should be LaunchScreen.
   [image]
2. Delete app on your device and restart your iPhone.
3. Clean Xcode project and reinstall the app.

That's all.

Comment: Thank you. But I've already finished your comments, but I can't. Among the simulators, the iPhone 11 pro max had a white screen, but the splash screen worked well when using the iPhone 11. I need to find out more about what's wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to explain more about issue. How did you make Launch.storyboard? I need to see your project settings and structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an image to you `LaunchScreen.storyboard`, I have both on that view and usually professional apps have also a `Splash` screen that is used to load data and prepare the next views where is usually found a logo or relevant image of the app.

The thing is that the `launch screen` is what first appears when the user taps the app icon before the app is finished launching. It can't be dynamic and it can't use any custom classes or code but your `splash screen` does, and there is where you should load your start logic (say check if the user is logged in and presenting them the login page if their are not or the main page if they are).

Also the splash screen should be a storyboard you create, exactly like any other view but one that you show at the beginning before doing anything else.

Comment: I can't understand the answer you explained. You have already added an image to LaunchScreen.storyboard. I know that the page that loads the splash data is LaunchScreen.storyboard. Is this not true? What do you mean that there is a screen that you usually use to prepare for the next view with a logo or an app-related image? You mean the main.storyboard?

Comment: Anyway thank you for your help. It hasn't been long since I started xcode, so I don't know much yet. I would appreciate it if you could also answer the questions in the comments.

Comment: The thing is that the launch screen is what first appears when the user taps the app icon before the app is finished launching. It can't be dynamic and it can't use any custom classes or code but your splash screen does, and there is where you should load your start logic (say check if the user is logged in and presenting them the login page if their are not of the main page if they are)