# Cordova overwrites iPhone splash screens

Tags: ios, visual-studio, cordova, splash-screen, visual-studio-cordova

I'm building a Cordova app for iOS using Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova 3.1 CTP in Visual Studio 2013 and I have a problem with the iPhone (and iPad) images. They are overwritten when the XCode project sent to be built on iOS is generated.

In the below image you can see on the left the images in my Visual Studio project. On the right side is the project sent to iOS opened in XCode. The images there are not the ones I've provided, but the default ones from Cordova.

[image]

As a result, the app gets built with the default splash screens, not the ones I've created.

My config.xml file contains the following:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <!-- 1st Gen, 3G & 3GS : 320×480   -->
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
    <!-- 4 & 4S            : 640×960   -->
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
    <!-- 5, 5C & 5S        : 640×1136  -->
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-568h-Portrait@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
    <!-- 6                 : 750×1334  -->
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-667h@2x~iphone.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-667h-Portrait@2x~iphone.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
    <!-- 6 Plus            : 1242×2208, downsampled to 1080 x 1920 -->
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-736h@3x~iphone.png" width="1080" height="1920"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-736h-Portrait@3x~iphone.png" width="1080" height="1920"/>
</platform>
```

I've see [Cordova iOS Splash Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180480/cordova-ios-splash-screen) and [Cordova 3.4 iOS white screen after splash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285888/cordova-3-4-ios-white-screen-after-splash/22354322#22354322) and I've done what's suggested there, but it didn't help.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

**UPDATE**: I have updated Cordova to version 5.1.1 both on Windows and Mac but it didn't help with the problem.

**UPDATE**: The problem was a blatant error, the folder name was `screens` not `screen`.

Comment: Did you replace the original ones inside `projectName/platforms/ios/projectName/Resources/splash`?

Comment: Yes. I put a screenshot, where you can see one of the images.