# PhoneGap 2.1 splash screen

Tags: ios, cordova, splash-screen

Our config.xml has

```
<gap:splash src="splash.png" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />
```

However when we upload to the Phonegap build (build.phonegap.com) service it is not giving us the splash screens in the iOS build/

Comment: Look at the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156841/phonegap-splash-screen-for-android-app

Answer (score 0):

Could you give us more information on what type of device you are using? If you are deploying your test application on an iphone 5, im afraid you are missing the splash screen for that. I ran into the same problem with my application. Try creating an image for iphone 5 which has the following screen dimension:

```
<gap:splash src="resources/images/ios/Default_iphone5.png"  width="640" height="1136" />
```