# Put icon before html5 app shows

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, smartphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [phonegap - splash screen for Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156841/phonegap-splash-screen-for-android-app)

I have an application built in Html5 and wrapped in PhoneGap for Android

Before app shows in SmartPhone has a black screen

instead of the black screen I want to put an icon.

how can I do it?

If there is a way to do it in JS and not in PhoneGap-it is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're talking about splash screens. Phonegap has splash screen support and it's easy to implement.

first of all, you add splashscreen plugin:

```
<plugin name="SplashScreen" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
```

Then in `onCreate` method of your main java file(the one that extends DroidGap), you add this line:

```
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
```

Then in javascript `deviceready` event, you can hide it:

```
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
```

See [API Docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html#Splashscreen)

Comment: Put the plugin in Manifest?

Comment: in the plugins.xml file, which is located in res/xml folder.