# How to make a HTML splashscreen for android phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova

I'm wondering how to make a HTML splash screen for android phonegap application instead of png image.

Comment: User experience: A spashcreen is already annoying when that's an image, but you really wan to load a webpage when a user is trying to start an application and discover your content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A HTML splash screen is pretty useless considering you will see the black screen of the app starting up then the white screen of the web view being created, then you'll have to wait for your html to be loaded. You are much better off using the native splash screen and dismissing it when your HTML is loaded.

[phonegap - splash screen for Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156841/phonegap-splash-screen-for-android-app/8157103#8157103)