# How to display a splash screen

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I have 2 questions regarding Sencha touch apps;

1.) How to add a default loading screen - When the app is opened it displays a white screen. Instead of this i want to display some animation.

2.) When the server is down, my application doesn't load, and it displays as alert box that says 'XXXXXXXX could not be opened because it could not connect to the server.'. This message appears even before the application is loaded. What i want to do is to Load the application (display tab bar, tableview etc) and then display the above error message in a alertview.

I think this is caused because i have added `autoLoad:true` for all Stores. How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the loading screen is that first your device loads the application (the white screen)  then sencha has to loaf it's code. The only way I have found to make splash screens work is to use Phone gap, and even then they are flaky at best.  I have however up voted your first question because I would love to hear any other opinions on it.

For store loading, I came up with what I think is a pretty decent solution for that problem. In each of my apps all of my stores extend from a custom local store which extends from Ext. Data. Store. The only function the for that base store is to onBeforeLoad check for a connection and take some appropriate action if there is none.

Please let me know if I can explain any of that better.

Good luck,

Brad

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PhoneGap there is a pretty good answer here: [phonegap - splash screen for Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156841/phonegap-splash-screen-for-android-app/8157103#8157103).

However, you'll also want to read the blog he links to because it is only part of the solution.  You'll want to turn off the splash screen as the application is loaded; otherwise you'll end up waiting for the timeout to expire.  In your app.html add something like this

```
<$cript type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    // Wait for Cordova to load
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    }
</$cript>
```