# splash screen error phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova

Im trying to add splash screen to my app, I modify my app.java to look like

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
```

and when I run the app I got an error saying `command failed with exit code 2`

I follow the instruction from here [phonegap - splash screen for Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156841/phonegap-splash-screen-for-android-app)

Comment: which version of phonegap are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions you have are very outdated. You can now run:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.splashscreen
```

Then you don't have to modify `app.java`

Also, make sure to have values set in `config.xml`:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
//splash is the name of the image without the extension
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="20000" />
//delay is optional
```

Additionally, make sure that for android the image is in the `/platforms/android/res/drawable` folder(s).

Lastly, make sure to run `cordova build` or `cordova run` after making these changes

[Documentation here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/blob/3d553eb51aa82a85789f410c36fb3f696fb38989/doc/index.md)

Comment: i included the plugin but still the splashscreen don't show

Comment: I modify my config.xml with this and nothing append, I create a new project and follow this steps and nothing :/

Comment: Do you have `splash.png` in `/platforms/android/res/drawable`?

Comment: there's an imagege icon.png

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the code to :

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
        // Set by  in config.xml
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html",3000);
    }