# Is it possible to add an HTML file as splash screen for Phonegap iOS app

Tags: html, ios, cordova

For a normal phonegap ios app we will be using an image as splash screen and we will be placing it in resource folder. Is it possible to load an html page as splash screen. My purpose is to load an remote image file which will be included in the html file. So that I can change the image saved in my server and thus change the splash screen image without changing the app source code.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible , but HTML splash screen is not a good idea considering you will see the black screen of the app starting up then the white screen of the web view being created, then you'll have to wait for your html to be loaded. Its better to use phonegap splash screen and dismiss it when your html loaded.

refer this: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156841/phonegap-splash-screen-for-android-app/8157103#8157103)