# PhoneGap SplashScreen - splash cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

i want to make a splash screen on my android application, i use phonegap.

here is my main.java code :

public class App extends DroidGap {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html",5000);
}
```

}

but i got an error : "splash cannot be resolved or is not a field"

i've put the splash.png on every drawable directories, but the error still there..

anybody could help me? thanks in advance..

Comment: Did you try clean and recompile ?

Comment: I assumed your using Eclipse, like me :) If you are choose menu Project - Clean.  If you have the Build Automatically option set it will compile for you when cleaning, otherwise you can compile again after clean.

Comment: what version of phonegap are you using

Comment: thanks for your advise but i still have the error :(

Comment: @K_Anas i use phonegap v.0.9.5.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is an issue about the timeout parameter in your case `5000` and it was fixed in phonegap 1.6.0 release that's why you don't get it work:

these links confirms that

[How to use OpenStreetMap/OpenLayers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100219/how-to-use-openstreetmap-openlayers/8101460#8101460)

[phonegap - splash screen for Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156841/phonegap-splash-screen-for-android-app)

try to use the last phone gap release (1.8.1) and you will get it work

Comment: if you don't get it work let me know and if phonegap 1.8.1 works for you don't forget to mark the answer as accepted

Comment: I am having the same issue in Phonegap 2.5.  My error said *"R cannot be resolved to a variable"* - I made sure my image exists in the "drawable" directory: `res/drawable/splash.png`

Answer (score 2):

just change the word splash by screen:

```
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.screen);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem.  I renamed the package which extended the core DroidGap class.  My solution was fixed by this solution: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3CHRujojc2o.  In short, make sure to update your references in the AndroidManifest.xml file to point to the new package name.